# NHibernate consumindo muita memória

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Eu possuo uma aplicação que realiza a conexão com a base de dados via `NHibernate`, com isso algumas operações são realizadas como `Save, Update e Delete`. Porém ao realizar esses procedimentos é incrível como o acúmulo de memória é feito não realizando de forma automática a dispensa de memória com o GC não utilizada pelo CLR.

Por exemplo: Uma consulta que retorna em média 1.000 rows acumula em média 100mb de memória, isso é normal ?

A implementação do código de conexão com a base está feita da seguinte forma:

```
  public ISession OpenConnection<T>(SelectDb dbConfigKey, DatabaseType dbType)
    {
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

        try
        {
            switch (dbType)
            {
                #region Conexão com a base de dados SQL Server 2000
                case DatabaseType.SQLServer2000:
                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2000
                      .ConnectionString(dbConfigKey.ToDescriptionDatabase())
                                  .ShowSql()
                    )
                   .Mappings(m =>
                              m.FluentMappings
                                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                    .Create(false, false))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Conexão com a base de dados SQL Server 2008
                case DatabaseType.SQLServer2008:
                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008
                      .ConnectionString(dbConfigKey.ToDescriptionDatabase())
                                  .ShowSql()
                    )
                   .Mappings(m =>
                              m.FluentMappings
                                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                    .Create(false, false))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Conexão com a base de dados PostgreSQL
                case DatabaseType.PostgreSQL:
                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(PostgreSQLConfiguration.Standard
                      .ConnectionString(dbConfigKey.ToDescriptionDatabase())
                                  .ShowSql()
                    )
                   .Mappings(m =>
                              m.FluentMappings
                                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                    .Create(false, false))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Conexão com a base de dados MYSQL
                case DatabaseType.MYSQL:
                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                      .ConnectionString(dbConfigKey.ToDescriptionDatabase())
                                  .ShowSql()
                    )
                   .Mappings(m =>
                              m.FluentMappings
                                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                    .Create(false, false))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Conexão com a base de dados Oracle9
                case DatabaseType.Oracle9:
                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle9
                      .ConnectionString(dbConfigKey.ToDescriptionDatabase())
                                  .ShowSql()
                    )
                   .Mappings(m =>
                              m.FluentMappings
                                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                    .Create(false, false))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    break;
                #endregion

                #region Conexão com a base de dados Oracle10
                case DatabaseType.Oracle10:
                    sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                    .Database(OracleClientConfiguration.Oracle10
                      .ConnectionString(dbConfigKey.ToDescriptionDatabase())
                                  .ShowSql()
                    )
                   .Mappings(m =>
                              m.FluentMappings
                                  .AddFromAssemblyOf<T>())
                    .ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)
                                                    .Create(false, false))
                    .BuildSessionFactory();
                    break;
                #endregion


            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            sessionFactory.Close();
            sessionFactory.Dispose();
        }
        return sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
```

onde **public ISession OpenConnection(SelectDb dbConfigKey, DatabaseType dbType)** recebe uma classe e passa por parâmetro a configuração da base de dados e o tipo de conexão.

Alguma dica para utilização de `Nhibernate` para esse tipo de finalidade ?

Answer (score 1):

A CLR não faz a limpeza automatica nesse caso, por isso o Dipose e o Close.

Frameworks de conexão com banco de dados "empacota" todo um trabalho complicado de alocar memória no server, fazer uma conexão com o banco, etc. Esse trabalho todo é feito por fora do .Net Runtime, por isso que é considerado como um **recurso não gerenciado**.

Por isso, o Garbage Collector não tem conhecimento desse recurso não gerenciado e não consegue fazer a limpeza de maneira eficiente deles (pensando que exista uma forma de limpar esse recurso dentro de um finalizador do objeto que empacota ele). Devido a isso é bem provável que você tenha problemas com memory leak.

O .Dispose() e o .Close() deveria ficar dentro do bloco finally, já que você não esta fechando a conexão com o banco em casos que não ocorra uma exceção.

```
try {
...
}
catch (Exception)
{
...
}
finally {
    //Faz o tratamento caso o seu switch cair em default por algum motivo.
    if (sessionFactory != null) {
        sessionFactory.Close();
        sessionFactory.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Sobre problemas relacionados a performance do NHibernante, fico devendo já que eu nunca trabalhei com ele.